# Angular. how not to repeat the same function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function, dry

This function works, but how It would be possible avoid typing the same for loop for a second variable and somehow use only one. Trying to Don't repeat yuorself method here. Do I need to use an array?

JS:

```
var app=angular.module('xpCalc', []);
app.controller('xpCalculatorController', function($scope){
$scope.currentLevel=1;
$scope.currentXp=function(){
    var output=0;
    for (var thisLVL=1; thisLVL < $scope.currentLevel; thisLVL++) {
        output += ( Math.floor ( thisLVL + 300 * Math.pow( 2, thisLVL / 7 ) ) / 4 );
    }
    return output;
  };
  $scope.desiredLevel=1;
  $scope.desiredXp=function(){
    var output=0;
    for (var thisLVL=1; thisLVL < $scope.desiredLevel; thisLVL++) {
        output += ( Math.floor ( thisLVL + 300 * Math.pow( 2, thisLVL / 7 ) ) / 4 );
    }
    return output;
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<h2>{{desiredXp()-currentXp()}}</h2>
```

Comment: First off, calculate `desiredXp()-currentXp()` in controller or service. After post result in HTML. Further, use `::` bindOnce, for example `<h2>{{::result}}</h2>`. Anyways its not good practice to use function in HTML, you call it every digest cycle

Comment: Just implement `getXP(level)` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var app=angular.module('xpCalc', []);
app.controller('xpCalculatorController', function($scope){
$scope.currentLevel=1;
$scope.currentXp=InternalLoop($scope.currentLevel);
$scope.desiredLevel=1;
$scope.desiredXp=InternalLoop($scope.desiredLevel);

function InternalLoop(level){
    var output=0;
    for (var thisLVL=1; thisLVL < level; thisLVL++) {
        output += ( Math.floor ( thisLVL + 300 * Math.pow( 2, thisLVL / 7 ) ) / 4 );
    }
    return output;
  };

});
```

Comment: You also should add `$watch` for input variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var app=angular.module('xpCalc', []);
app.controller('xpCalculatorController', function($scope){
$scope.currentLevel=1;
var getResult = function(level)
{
   var output=0;
   for (var thisLVL=1; thisLVL < level; thisLVL++) {
     output += (Math.floor(thisLVL+300*Math.pow(2,thisLVL/7))/4);
   }
   return output;
}
$scope.currentXp=getResult($scope.currentLevel);
$scope.desiredLevel=1;
$scope.desiredXp=getResult($scope.desiredLevel);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Task:

- `xp = sum[floor(i + 300*2^(i/7)) / 4], i = 1..level`
- `4*xp = sum[i] + sum[floor(300*2^(i/7))], i = 1..level`
- `4*xp = level*(level+1)/2 + sum[floor(300*2^(i/7))], i = [1..level)`

We come to next function:

```
function getXP(level) {
  var xp = level*(level+1)/2, i;
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < level; i++)
    sum+=Math.floor(300 * Math.pow(2, i/7));
  return (xp + sum) / 4;
}
```

However, `getXP(5) - getXP(3)` will equal like we skip first 3 steps

```
function getXP(to, from) {
  from = from || 1;
  var xp = 0, i;
  for (i = from; i < level; i++)
    sum += i + Math.floor(300 * Math.pow(2, i/7));
  return xp / 4;
}
```

So, you can now use it like `{{getXP(desiredLevel, currentLevel)}}`

---

This function will be called each digest iteration. It's bad.

You have at least two options to deal with it:

- Calculate result in your controller and `watch` about arguments to recalc it.
- Memoize your function

Something like this:

```
var hash = {};
function mgetXP(to, from) {
  if (typeof hash[key(to, from)] != 'undefined') return hash[key(to, from)];
  return hash[key(to, from)] = getXP(to, from);
  function key(to, from) {return [to, from].join('_'); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this approach:

```
$scope.currentLevel=1;
$scope.currentXp = xp($scope.currentLevel);
$scope.desiredLevel=1;
$scope.desiredXp = xp($scope.desiredLevel);

function xp(level) {    
   function calc(index, result){
      if (index >= level) return result;
      result += (Math.floor( index + 300 * Math.pow( 2, index / 7 ) ) / 4);
      return calc(index + 1, result);
   }
   return calc(1, 0);    
}
```